# How do I convert from url to embed code for vimeo youtube etc. using Javascript

Tags: javascript, embed

I have this code

```
var videoreg = new RegExp(/^(<iframe.*? src=")(.*?)(\??)(.*?)(".*)$/mg);

     if( document.getElementById('area1').value.match(videoreg))
     {

   var c1 = document.getElementById('area1').value;
   var divElement = document.createElement("div");  
   divElement.id = "myDiv";  
   divElement.className = "myDivClass";  
   divElement.innerHTML = c1;  
   document.body.appendChild(divElement); 
   form1.reset();
   var button = document.getElementById("remove");
   button.addEventListener("click", function() {
       divElement.parentNode.removeChild(divElement);
   });
    }
    else{
    alert("Please insert correct embed code!");
    }

}
```

I want to change it so that I paste in a url and it changes it to embed code then a iframe appears on the screen.

Comment: So what is the specific problem or question? You posted code but gave no indication of what's wrong, any errors thrown or what it should do differently

Comment: I want to convert from url to embed code and customize the code \i have pasted

Comment: That doesn't explain where you are having problems or what *"customize"* needs to do that code isn't currently doing

Comment: That code takes enables one to paste an embed code from youtube vimeo etc and press a button which pastes the iframe onto the screen, I just want to instead take the url and do the same but I'd have to convert the url to embed code in the javascript

Comment: So what have you tried to reverse it? The reverse is actually simpler